# Protractor Multiple Size Browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

So for a web app that I'm working on, I'm using Protractor JS to test it - I'm writing it in the mobile-first style, so resizing shouldn't be an issue. Is there a way to get it to tests multiple sizes without huge amounts of repeated code? Writing a test repeated multiple times different sizing using a

```
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(x, y);
```

with multiple values of x and y seems pretty inefficient, but I'm not sure I can think of something better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would *dynamically create tests* based on a pre-defined array of sizes:

```
describe("Testing multiple browser sizes", function () {
    var sizes = [
        {x: 800, y: 600},
        {x: 300, y: 200}
    ];

    sizes.map(function(size) {
        it("should pass the test on browser size: x='" + size.x + "', y='" + size.y + "'", function() {
            browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(size.x, size.y);
            # test logic
        });
    }
});
```

This would help you to follow the [*DRY principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).