# Using parameter in beforeEach() of Protractor

Tags: protractor

Is there any way to get method name or data values from jasmine data provider in beforeEach() of protractor; as we can do with testNg- beforeMethod() in selenium?

TestNg before Method-
 beforeMethod(final Object[] data,final Method method)

Similarly I want in beforeEach() of protrcator.

Comment: Can you provide example of jasmine data provider?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-data-provider

Answer (score 2):

One thing I would suggest is to define your data values in a separate module and then import to your spec file.

```js
    // Your data in its own module
    'use strict'

    module.exports = {
        browserSizes : {
            'Browser 1': {x: 800, y: 600},
            'Browser 2': {x: 300, y: 200}
        }
    }
```

Then include it in your beforeEach like so:

```js
    var setBrowser = require('path_to_your_module');
    var using = require('jasmine-data-provider');

    describe('a cool test', function() {
        
        using(setBrowser.browserSizes, function(data, description) {
            
            beforeEach(function() {
                browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(data.x, data.y);
            });

        ... more code here ...

        }
    }
```

This way all you have to do is add new browser sizes to the module file and you have access to it whereever you need it in your spec file. I wrote a tutorial on how to use Jasmine Data Provider in this way here if you wanted to check out the specifics

http://moduscreate.com/protractor-and-jasmine-data-provider-write-once-test-many/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach, as @alexce suggested

[Protractor Multiple Size Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468427/protractor-multiple-size-browsers/37472582#37472582)

```
describe("Testing multiple browser sizes", function () {
var sizes = [
    {x: 800, y: 600},
    {x: 300, y: 200}
];

sizes.map(function(size) {
    it("should pass the test on browser size: x='" + size.x + "', y='" + size.y + "'", function() {
        browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(size.x, size.y);
        # test logic
    });
}
});
```

you maybe don't need jasmine-data-provider, just concatenate to spec name what you need.